# How to print the first element of matching conditions with numpy where or convert it to an integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find automatically as a function of minimum value and maximum with a tolerance chosen, the indexes of an array which is in these 2 intervals. For this, I did (if I want the values of array to be located bewteen 7e-4 and 3e-3.

```
## Want to plot roughly between 7e-4 and 3e-3
  minStep = 7e-4
  maxStep = 3e-3
  # Tolerance : could be calculated in theory
  minTol = 1.5e-1
  maxTol = 1.5e-1
  for j in range(len(stepNewArray)):
    if (np.isclose(stepNewArray[j], minStep, atol=minTol)):
      # Find final index :  don't forget to cast into integer
      indexFirst = np.where((stepNewArray >= (minStep-minTol)) & (stepNewArray <= (minStep+minTol)))
    else:
      # Value not found
      print('Minimum value not found : change tolerance')

  for j in range(len(stepNewArray)):
    if (np.isclose(stepNewArray[j], maxStep, atol=maxTol)):
      # Find final index :  don't forget to cast into integer
      indexLast = np.where((stepNewArray >= (maxStep-maxTol)) & (stepNewArray <= (maxStep+maxTol)))
    else:
      # Value not found
      print('Maximum value not found : change tolerance')
        
  print('indexFirst ', np.array(indexFirst)[0])
  print('indexLast  ', np.array(indexLast)[0])
```

But for ouput of print, I get :

```
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
etc ...
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Minimum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
etc ...
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
Maximum value not found : change tolerance
('indexFirst ', array([95, 96, 97]))
('indexLast  ', array([103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112]))
###################################
Current parameter : Omega_m
###################################
idMultipole = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_Derivatives_INTERVAL_between_7e-4_AND_3e-3.py", line 253, in <module>
    for idStep in range(indexFirst,indexLast+1):
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I don't know how to convert the first index found, respecting the `np.where` conditions) to an integer or simply print it.

I tried also with :

```
  print('indexFirst = %d ' % int(np.array(indexFirst[0])))
  print('indexLast = %d ' %  int(np.array(indexLast[0])))
```

But I get also an error :

```
    print('indexFirst = %d ' % int(np.array(indexFirst[0])))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I don't know what to do to get the first indices matching the multiple conditions of `np.where`, to print them and mostly to get the integer type for them (indexFirst and indexLast).

I am using Python 2.7 (I know, sorry, this is outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try a simple `np.where()` with no `x, y` arguments:

```
np.where((True, True, False, True))
>>> (array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

You'll notice it returns a tuple of the index on each axis.  You only have one axis, so it's a one-item tuple.

You just need to drill into that one more level, `indexFirst[0][0]`